# privlage issues when attempting to run the passenger-status command from within a rubyscript

Tags: ruby, centos, passenger, collectd

I wrote a collectd plugin in ruby that is suppose to check passengers status and report back the various metrics. When I test my script on the all works well, but when I attempt to run my script through collectd it fails with the following message.

> > "ERROR: You are not authorized to query the status for this Phusion Passenger instance. Please try again with 'sudo'."

I then changed my ruby script to use the sudo command for passenger status which resulted in

> > "exec plugin: exec_read_one: error = sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo"

I then tried getting collectd to run the script as root but I got the following

> > "exec plugin: Cowardly refusing to exec program as root."

I am not sure what else I can try. the command that is failing when used by a user other that root is `passenger-status`

Here is the script

> > `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`
> >     require 'getoptlong'
> >
> > `# The name of the collectd plugin, something like apache, memory, mysql, interface, ...`
> >     PLUGIN_NAME = 'passenger-status'
> >
> > def usage
> >       puts("#{$0} -h  [-i ]")
> >       exit
> >     end
> >
> > `# Main`
> >     begin
> >       # Sync stdout so that it will flush to collectd properly.
> >       $stdout.sync = true
> >
> > # Parse command line options
> >       hostname = nil
> >       sampling_interval = 20 # sec, Default value
> >       opts = GetoptLong.new(
> >           [ '--hostid', '-h', GetoptLong::REQUIRED_ARGUMENT ],
> >           [ '--sampling-interval', '-i', GetoptLong::OPTIONAL_ARGUMENT ]
> >       )
> >       opts.each do |opt, arg|
> >         case opt
> >           when '--hostid'
> >             hostname = arg
> >           when '--sampling-interval'
> >             sampling_interval = arg.to_i
> >         end
> >       end
> >       usage if !hostname
> >
> > # Collection loop
> >       while true do
> >         start_run = Time.now.to_i
> >         next_run = start_run + sampling_interval
> >
> > ```
> > # collectd data and print the values
> > data = `passenger-status`
> > max = data.match(/max (.*)/).to_s.split.last
> > count = data.match(/count (.*)/).to_s.split.last
> > active = data.match(/active (.*)/).to_s.split.last
> > inactive = data.match(/inactive (.*)/).to_s.split.last
> > waiting = data.match(/Waiting on global queue: ([\d]+)/).to_s.split.last
> > puts("PUTVAL #{hostname}/#{PLUGIN_NAME}/gauge-max_allowed_connections #{start_run}:#{max}")
> > puts("PUTVAL #{hostname}/#{PLUGIN_NAME}/gauge-thread_count #{start_run}:#{count}")
> > puts("PUTVAL #{hostname}/#{PLUGIN_NAME}/gauge-threads_active #{start_run}:#{active}")
> > puts("PUTVAL #{hostname}/#{PLUGIN_NAME}/gauge-threads_inactive #{start_run}:#{inactive}")
> > puts("PUTVAL #{hostname}/#{PLUGIN_NAME}/gauge-waiting_in_queue #{start_run}:#{waiting}")
> >
> > # sleep to make the interval
> > while((time_left = (next_run - Time.now.to_i)) > 0) do
> >   sleep(time_left)
> > end
> > ```
> >
> > end
> >     end

Comment: Can you show us the code you've tried? That would help.

Comment: I have added the entire script to my OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into the `phusion_passenger/admin_tools/server_instance.rb` file I was able to determine what file passenger was using to make the determination weather a user would be able to run the passenger-status command or not.

`filename = "#{@generation_path}/passenger-status-password.txt"
                                        password = File.open(filename, "rb") do |f|
                                                f.read
                                        end
                                rescue Errno::EACCES
                                        raise RoleDeniedError`

the file it was trying to read was `passenger-status-password.txt` this file is located in the `/tmp/passenger.1.0.19198/generation-1/`directory for Passenger version 3.0.9 on CentOS 5.7. I chmod'd the file to 644 and this fixed the issue. this solution also applies if someone wants to run the passenger-status command without sudo.